# magento password change with soap

Tags: php, magento, soap, magento-1.9

I am connecting an other application to create and update customers in Magento 1.9 with SOAP. Because I want the passwords to stay exactly the same customers will be forced to change the password in the other application. After change I want the password to be changed in Magento Through the SOAP connection, but I can't get it working. After the request I am getting "bool(true)" but nothing seems to be changed.

Am I doing something wrong, or are there restrictions in Magento.

My code:

```
<?php
//ensure you are getting error output for debug
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$client = new SoapClient('http://www.mymagentosite.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

// If some stuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiuser', 'apikey');

// CustomerID search
$params = array('complex_filter'=>
    array(
        array('key'=>'email','value'=>array('key' =>'eq','value' => $email)),

    ),

);
$result = $client->customerCustomerList($session, $params);

var_dump ($result);

$customerID = $result[0]->customer_id;
// echo $customerID;

// Update Customer
$result2 = $client->customerCustomerUpdate($session, $customerID, array('password' => 'newpassword'));

var_dump ($result2);
```

Comment: Already found an answer..: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/72253/

Comment: the link doesn't work, do you know why the password doesn't change ?

Answer (score 1):

It's very strange.
The doc (and the wsdl) wants you to pass the `password` parameter.
I've tried to investigate in the code (Magento 1.7 series).
Before setting the values you have passed through the API call, in the corresponding `update()` function of the `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Api.php` file, there is this code:

```
foreach ($this->getAllowedAttributes($customer) as $attributeCode=>$attribute) {
        if (isset($customerData[$attributeCode])) {
            $customer->setData($attributeCode, $customerData[$attributeCode]);
        }   
    }
```

So, I've tried to print the allowed attributes, and `password` is not present. What is present is `password_hash`, but this field is not present in the doc, and, more important, is not present in the wsdl.

Just to make a test, I've tried to pass the `md5` value of the password I wanted to pass as the `password` argument, then, in the `_prepareData` function that is called in the `update` function, I've added this line of code:

```
$data['password_hash'] = $data['password'];
```

The result is that the password is successfully changed, and I can login with the new password.

Now, of course this is not the way to proceed.
First of all, I'm changing a core file.
Then, probably, it's possible to update the list of the allowed attributes adding the `password` attribute, but you have to remember to build the md5 version of the password, not the "clear text" one, and in any case rename it to `password_hash` somewhere.
Another solution is to customize (not in `core/`, again) the wsdl parameters related to the complex type `customerCustomerEntityToCreate`, adding `password_hash`.